# How does TextView display (changes to) its text?

Tags: android, textview, paint, android-paint

I am wondering how android's `android.widget.TextView` is working. I went through the code of the class and searched for explanations, however, i was unable to figure out the key questions . Particularly i am interested in two parts:

1. **How is text being displayed?**
2. **What happens when the `TextView` is editable (basically an `EditText`) and the user inputs a letter?**

I know that at some point `TextPaint` is being used, however i could not figure out where it gets the canvas to draw on and how much exactly is being drawn (only the changed part or the entire text?).

Comment: At the end everything is drawn using OpenGL because everything else is too slow.

Comment: It...might actually be Vulkan in the end rather than OpenGL?  Don't quote me on that, though.  It's whatever backend Skia is using on Android.  But I think this question is asking about a higher level than that.